# is it possible to find carbon footprint on AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to understand if it is at all possible to find what would be the carbon footprint of my Python function running on AWS Lambda?

At the time, where almost all aspects of a function run can be accounted for and allocated a financial cost, it would be great to know what is the climate cost of this.

Does anyone have any link/resource which talks about this?

thank you